# How can I only show the request header/response headers and output to /dev/null when using wget?

Tags: wget

How can I only show the request header/response headers and output to /dev/null  when using wget?

I use `--debug` it shows the request headers and response headers:

```
wget --debug https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/internal-cs/default/beacon.js
```

I want use `-o /dev/null` to not save content, but it do not shows the headers now:

```
wget --debug https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/internal-cs/default/beacon.js -o /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal view is that wget is not the right tool for the job, however I managed to force it to do this -

```
 wget -S https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/internal-cs/default/beacon.js -q -O /dev/null
```

The key elements of this command are  -S means show headers, -q means supress output from wget, and -O (capital O) means write to a file.

I would be inclined to use CURL for this - with a command like

```
curl -sD - -O  https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/internal-cs/default/beacon.js
```

Comment: But how to display the request header?